# ConnectivityExtension: ConnectivityExt jar file not present

Tags: logging

When using `adb logcat` to get debug messages from my phone, I get many of those lines:

```
04-23 18:16:51.085  1428  1951 W ConnectivityExtension: ConnectivityExt jar file not present
04-23 18:16:51.187  1428  1951 W ConnectivityExtension: ConnectivityExt jar file not present
04-23 18:16:51.658  1428  1951 W ConnectivityExtension: ConnectivityExt jar file not present
```

Where is this coming from?
What can I do to get rid of those message?

I'm running LineageOS 14.1-20180314-crackling (Android 7.1.2) on a Wileyfox Swift. I don't have any google apps (nor google play services) installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searching around, it turns out `ConnectivityExt` is a proprietary Qualcomm file ([source](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=org%3ALineageOS%20ConnectivityExt%20jar&type=Code) - you can see that it is included in the proprietary-files.txt in LineageOS), related to the Qualcomm package `com.qualcomm.qti.tetherstatsextension.tetherstatsreporting`. I found some code  for this [here, line 107 onwards](https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/scm/git/frameworks-base/commits/9b0499db993e2bb471cb88f6d1ce69ce5262b225). As it seems to be about `TetherStatsReporting`, maybe it is related to hotspot? Considering it is proprietary I do not think you can do anything about it.